# how to fail the GoCD build based on the sonar quality gate?

Tags: go-cd

how to fail the GO build based on the sonar quality gate?

I expect the stage to be failed when gateway fails. Is there any configurations that can be done to fail the build

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @moritz answer, this worked for me.

I created a bat file that would check for the status code of the SONAR project, after the SONAR build is executed and based on the status of the response, would return the exit code.

```
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"curl  http://mysonarserver/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=com.mypackage:sampleproject | jq ".projectStatus.status""') Do Set "test=%%~A"
echo %test%
If /I "%test%"=="ERROR" exit -1
If /I "%test%"=="OK" exit 0
```

In my case, the SONAR server would return ERROR and OK based on the status of the build.

I have used curl and jq for making the http request from the command line and to parse the response to json respectively.

I had to do some tweaking to make it work on Windows, hopefully it should work on Linux as well.

You can also add the call to the Maven build for Sonar from this script if needed.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

GoCD fails the task (and thus stage and job, unless configured otherwise) when the exit code is non-zero.

So you need to bring whatever command you are executing to indicate a failure through a non-zero exit code (which most UNIX commands do).

Comment: @mortiz Can you please help by sharing an example of how to do it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't have any examples, since I have no experience with Sonar. Sorry.